# Confusing single And & operator and how to record it in database

Tags: c#, sql, database, logic, logical-operators

So I saw this logic somewhere and I'm confused with it. Why is the code below return false? The easiest explanation for this and single & or | operator ***for dummies***??

```
enum Colors{
    yellow,
    red,
    blue,
    green
}

var requestedColor = Colors.yellow;
var matchedColor = Colors.red | Colors.blue;

var result = (requestedColor & matchedColor ) == matchedColor ;
```

Another thing is previously there can only be one value in requestedColor in database.
say I want to change and record it like matchedColor value in database, what would be the best way?

Comment: This isn't valid C# code

Comment: nor it's valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

An enum is just a representation of an integer, so here we have, by default:

```
yellow = 0    
red = 1    
blue = 2    
green = 3
```

if we consider that in binary, its

```
yellow = 0000    
red =    0001    
blue =   0010    
green =  0011
```

the single `|` and `&` are known as bitwise 'or' and 'and'. They perform those operations one bit at a time, so

```
Colors.red | Colors.blue
```

is `0001 | 0010` which is `0011` (green)

wheares, say

```
Colors.red & Colors.blue
```

would be `0000` (yellow).

This is almost certainly not what you want. You are using the enum flags convention, but to do it you need to set your values precisely (note, I've changed the capitilization to follow normal conventions):

```
enum Colors{
    Yellow  = 1,
    Red = 2,
    Blue = 4,
    Green = 8
}
```

In terms of bits this gives:

```
Yellow = 0001    
Red =    0010    
Blue =   0100    
Green =  1000
```

This means each colour has its own unique bit. Now when we do

```
Colors.Red | Colors.Blue
```

we get `0010 | 0100` giving `0110`. This doesn't represent a single colour, but both Red and Blue together. (Note, not the combined colour Magenta - it's simply storing both colours as a group together in the same variable.) As many or as few colours as you like can be stored in the one variable.

We can then use `&` to verify if a colour is in the group:

```
var requestedColor = Colors.Yellow;
var matchedColor = Colors.Red | Colors.Rlue;

var result = (requestedColor & matchedColor ) != 0 ; // Note, the original code was wrong here we shouldn't compare with matchedColor
```

So `requestColor` is `0110` and `matchedColor` `0001`. `0110 & 0001` gives `0000` which doesn't equal zero, so we get false - Yellow is not found in the group.

On the other hand, if requestedColor  were Red (`0010`) then `requestedColor & matchedColor` is `0110 & 0010`, giving `0010`, which does not equal zero, so we get true. Red is in the group.

One last thing. When you are using a enum for this purpose, its best to indicate it with an attribute specially designed for this purpose, so that the compiler can correctly generate string representations of the group, so the correct code is

```
[Flags]
enum Colors{
    Yellow  = 1,
    Red = 2,
    Blue = 4,
    Green = 8
}

var requestedColor = Colors.Yellow;
var matchedColor = Colors.Red | Colors.Blue;

var result = (requestedColor & matchedColor) != 0;
```

As to storing it in a database, just store it as an integer and cast it back to the `enum` when you fetch it out.